# SQL Select Sequential Dates with Additional Lookup Values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to grab a series of dates and the corresponding values (if any) that exist in my database.

I have two parameters - today (date using getDate()) - and a number of days (integer). For this example, I'm using the value 10 for the days.

Code to get the sequential dates for 10 days after today:

```
SELECT  top 10 DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (ORDER BY object_id), REPLACE(getDate(),'-','')) as Alldays
FROM sys.all_objects
```

I now need to look up several values for each day in the sequential days code, which may or may not exist in the time table (we assume 8 hours for all dates, unless otherwise specified). The lookup would be on the field recordDateTime. If no "hours" value exists in the table cap_time for that date, I need to return a default value of 8 as the number of hours. Here's the base query:

```
                SELECT u.FullName as UserName, d2.department, 
                recordDateTime, ISNULL(hours,8) as hours  
                FROM cap_time c
                left join user u on c.userID = u.userid
                left join dept d2 on u.deptID = d2.DeptID
                WHERE c.userid = 38 AND u.deptID = 1
```

My end result for the next 10 days should be something like:
Date (sequential), Department, UserName, Number of Hours

I can accomplish this using TSQL and a temp table, but I'd like to see if this can be done in a single statement. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you want to get a list of the next ten days and then, regardless of whether they have a record, select those dates + any record that may exist for those dates? Or do you just need any date in the next ten days (if it exists)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And if there is no record, return the default of 8 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any DDL or sample data it's hard to determine exactly what you need.

I think this will get you pretty close (note my comments):

```
-- sample data
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @table TABLE 
(
  fullName   varchar(10), 
  department varchar(10), 
  [hours]    tinyint, 
  somedate   date
);

INSERT @table VALUES 
('bob', 'sales', 5, getdate()+1), 
('Sue', 'marketing', 3, getdate()+2),
('Sue', 'sales', 12, getdate()+4),
('Craig', 'sales', 4, getdate()+8),
('Joe', 'sales', 18, getdate()+9),
('Fred', 'sales', 10, getdate()+10);

--SELECT * FROM @table
;

-- solution
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WITH alldays([day]) AS -- logic to get your dates for a LEFT date table
(
  SELECT TOP (10) 
    CAST(DATEADD
    (
      DAY, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id), 
      getdate()
    ) AS date) 
  FROM sys.all_objects
)
SELECT d.[day], t.fullName, department, [hours] = ISNULL([hours], 8)
FROM alldays d
LEFT JOIN @table t ON d.[day] = t.somedate;
```

Results:

```
day        fullName   department hours
---------- ---------- ---------- -----
2017-04-12 bob        sales      5
2017-04-13 Sue        marketing  3
2017-04-14 NULL       NULL       8
2017-04-15 Sue        sales      12
2017-04-16 NULL       NULL       8
2017-04-17 NULL       NULL       8
2017-04-18 NULL       NULL       8
2017-04-19 Craig      sales      4
2017-04-20 Joe        sales      18
2017-04-21 Fred       sales      10
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a subquery and the in statement, like:

```
SELECT u.FullName as UserName, d2.department, 
            recordDateTime, ISNULL(hours,8) as hours  
            FROM cap_time c
            left join user u on c.userID = u.userid
            left join dept d2 on u.deptID = d2.DeptID
            WHERE c.userid = 38 AND u.deptID = 1 and recordDateTime in 
                 (SELECT  top 10 DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() 
                  OVER (ORDER BY object_id), REPLACE(getDate(),'-','')) as Alldays
                  FROM sys.all_objects)
```